# How to remove gridlines from combo chart generated using Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have the following code which generate d a combo chart which I have generated using Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);


  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Days', 'Seat Utilization', 'RevPash'],
     ['Monday',  .61,      34.33],
     ['Tuesday',  .59,      33.15],
     ['Wednesday',  .64,      34.83],
     ['Thursday',  .62,      32.85],
     ['Friday',  .73,      37.30],
     ['Saturday',  .89,      49.76],
     ['Sunday',  .87,      45.99]
  ]);
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                            { //calc: "stringify",
                                sourceColumn: 1,
                                type: "number",
                                role: "annotation" },2]);
var options = {
  title : '',
  vAxes: {0: {title: "",titleTextStyle: {italic: false},gridlines: { color: 'transparent'}}, 1: {title: "",titleTextStyle: {italic: false},format: 'percent'},gridlines: { color: 'transparent'} },
  hAxis: {title: 'Days',titleTextStyle: {italic: false},gridlines: { color: 'transparent'},textStyle : {fontSize: 9 } },
  chartArea: {'width': '90%', 'height': '80%'},
  seriesType: 'bars',
  series: {1: {type: 'area'}},
  legend: { position: 'top' },
  height: 300,

  series: {
        1:{ type: "area", targetAxisIndex: 0, color:'#EA922B' },
        0:{ type: "bars", targetAxisIndex: 1, color:'#20488D' },
        2:{ type: "bars", targetAxisIndex: 1, color:'#94CAFC' },


    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_combo'));
chart.draw(view, options);
 }
</script>
```

The chart looks like this:

[image]

What shall I do to remove the gridlines?? I have tried the option to make the gridlines transparant, but for some reason it is not working. I am unable to understand that how I can remove the gridlines. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a typo in the definition for `gridlines` on vAxes `1`...

`gridlines: {color: 'transparent'}`
is defined outside the object curly braces

change from...
`vAxes: {0: {title: "",titleTextStyle: {italic: false},gridlines: { color: 'transparent'}}, 1: {title: "",titleTextStyle: {italic: false},format: 'percent'},gridlines: { color: 'transparent'} }`

to...
`vAxes: {0: {title: "",titleTextStyle: {italic: false},gridlines: { color: 'transparent'}}, 1: {title: "",titleTextStyle: {italic: false},format: 'percent',gridlines: { color: 'transparent'}} }`

Answer (score 0):

`vAxis: {
gridlines: {color: 'none'}
}`

[eidt]
Works in the fiddle linked from this google docs developer wiki: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#formatting-axis-gridline-and-tick-labels

Comment: No that does not work for me :( Moreover the fiddle link is redirecting me to an empty fiddle. Any other method?

Comment: I've updated my answer to give the right link, where you can find the fiddle. Is it significant that you're referring to `hAxes` (plural) but `vAxis` (singular)? Is that valid?